# Create code behind file after aspx has been created

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I just inherited a web site that was created by a designer.  The site was originally created with all *.html files.  The designer renamed all the *.html files to *.aspx files.  Hence there are no aspx.cs files created.  I pulled the site into a new VS2012 solution.  My question is, is there a way in VS 2010 to automatically create the code behind files for a an existing stand alone aspx file?

Comment: You can't, not really - just renaming a HTML file does not an ASPX make - you need the declaring header at the top, for example, which references the class, code behind etc. It would be easier to rename the files back and then just add new ASPX pages and copy the HTML into those. How many files do you have?

Comment: A tool to automate this would be awesome.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know of an automated way to do this, but if there is no server side code in the existing *.aspx files then it should just be a case of adding the .cs codebehind files and then wiring them up in the `<%@ Page` tag like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="YourPageTitle" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YourPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourNamespace.YourPage" %>
```

Note: This will not create the `YourPage.aspx.designer.cs` file. (I usually delete these anyway as they cause merge issues - i find it easier to add the controls i need to reference to my code-behind file manually.)

The other alternative is to just create a new "Web Form" for each page with the correct names and then copy and paste the existing markup into them. If you do have server code in the existing *.aspx files then you will need to manually copy it to the code-behind.

Comment: Sounds like the only way to do it is manually creating the files.  Sounds like one for the suggestion box.

Comment: @MikeMurphy Yeah, I had a look through a few of the VS2010 extensions like `VSCommands` and `Productivity Power Tools`. I'm still not convinced they can't help with this, but i couldn't find anything in my initial search. If you have more time than i did to search, i'm pretty sure you could find something that does what you need. Failing that you could always create your own extension?

Comment: If you have ReSharper installed, it will do the job for you.

Answer (score 9):

Based on what I found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1229894.aspx/1

1. Right click on your solution explorer.
2. Add New Item -> Class File.
3. Name the file as the name of your aspx eg: Default.aspx.cs
4. When it asks you the file should be in app_code click "no".
5. In your aspx in page attribute add

   ```
   AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default"
   ```
6. Similarly in your class file that you just added remove everything. Your class should look like this:

   ```
   //all namespaces go here


   public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why Default?   Shouldn't it be the name of whatever page you are creating?  Surely you'll have hundreds of these pages  Shouldn't the code behinds all be different?  Would it not then be the name of the webpage in both cases (the cs file and the aspx page?

Comment: Default is just used as an example. Feel free to clean it up if you can.

Answer (score 5):

After you add the new .cs file, you may want to see the file look like a codebehind file (indented, icon, etc). To do so:

1. Unload the project
2. Edit the project
3. Find the new filename (file.aspx.cs) in the  section with files.
4. Add an xml node for DependentUpon.
5. Save and Close the project
6. Reload the project

For a file Profile.aspx.cs, the xml should look something like this:

```
<Compile Include="Profile.aspx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Profile.aspx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Comment: For me, I just closed Visual Studio, edited the Project, and re-opened the Solution. Thanks for the reminder on where the CS and ASPX are linked.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2012: Right click on the project --> click Add --> click Web Form --> Copy the content of your original aspx file into the new WebForm aspx --> delete the original aspx file --> Rename the new one to anything you want. 
Now you should have a new aspx file with a code behind file that is ready for use

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself from the drama of manually editing the project file like David Frette details, I suggest you remove the file from the project and create a new file with the same name *with* a code-behind. Then copy-paste the contents of the original aspx or ascx to the new files.