# Where do I find the class referenced in an .aspx page's "Inherits" property?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, code-behind

I added an as-minimal-as-possible .aspx.vb file so that the corresponding .aspx would not complain about it missing. I used what G. Stoynex recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223044/what-is-the-preferred-workaround-when-an-aspx-files-code-behind-file-is-missin).

The error about the missing .aspx.vb file is no longer thrown, but now I get, "*Context' is not a member of 'cms_CreateDateRange'*." on this line at the tope of the .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="CreateDateRange.aspx.vb" Title="Create Date Range" Inherits="cms_CreateDateRange" %>
```

I don't know what this err msg is trying to tell me, really, but I reckon that "cms_CreateDateRange" is a class, and the compiler expects it to have a member named "Context'.

But right-clicking cms_CreateDateRange and selecting "Navigate To..." doesn't take me anywhere, however displays these options:

[image]

I don't what this all means or which, if any, option I should select.

So where can I locate the class referenced in an .aspx page's "Inherits" property, and what is the minimal addition I can make to it to prevent the new error ("Context is not a member..." from being thrown?

Comment: Every `.aspx` file has also a `.aspx.vb` file and a `.aspx.designer.vb` file. It is possible that these files are missing. Take a look in the folder and see if these file exist.

Comment: No, they don't exist. For most of the .aspx files there are .aspx.vb files, but no designer files. And the few .aspx files that have no corresponding .aspx.vb file are wreaking havoc and mayhem; the project is trumpified.

Comment: One trick that helped me more than once is to delete the problematic file and recreate it so that Visual Studio adds these files as well. If the file has any content, copy and paste it somewhere (e.g. to Notepad) so you don't lose any code.

Comment: Make sure you have selected "Show All Files" in your solution explorer. cms_CreateDateRange should almost certainly be found in CreateDateRange.aspx.vb. Alternatively, open your .aspx page and hit F7.
Oh, I see this is an addition from a previous issue of yours. While it is a bit ridiculous I have found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20953763/1316573) to be the most reliable.

Comment: I had to create the nonexistent .aspx.vb manually, with minimal info. All it has is Public Class CreateDateRange
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
End Class